# What is the Windows registered class of a Java window?

Tags: java, c++, windows

I am writing a C++ app that retrieves a Java window and sets it as maximized. I am wondering what the registered class of a Java window is for `FindWindow(LPCTSTR lpClassName, LPCTSTR lpWindowName);`

Comment: I expect you could use Spy++ to find out the answer yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JRE 1.6, Win32 Window class name for the top-level application window is set to `SunAwtFrame`. Prior to 1.6 it was inherited from the Java class name. Here are some [details](http://www.java.net/node/659065).